# Can I create a DOM Document from an encoded UTF-8 byte array?

Tags: java, android, xml, dom

My situation:
I have a method that accepts a byte array. The array in question is encoded using UTF-8 and was originally an XML message. I would like to be able to re-construct this message using a DOM parser. I know I can create a Document from a byte array through the use of a `ByteBuffer`. The only problem is that if I put this directly into action on the passed byte array, it will create a corrupted Document (if possible at all). That is because the array is an encoded XML message, encoded in UTF-8. However, when I decode the array by the use of  the decode() method, I get a CharBuffer returned:

```
ByteBuffer encodedData = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
CharBuffer decodedData = Charset.forName("UTF-8").decode(encodedData);
```

I don't know how to construct a Document from this, as there are no parse() methods defined in the DocumentBuilder that will accept a CharBuffer....

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DocumentBuilder` has a `parse(InputStream is)` method, you can create your document by passing in a `ByteArrayInputStream` created from your bytes.

```
Document doc = DocumentBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
```

Comment: Just as a note: This is one of the rare cases where you *don't* need to specify the encoding, because XML data has to contain enough information to find out the encoding itself (if it's well-formed).